# How processing-hungry are opencv backgroundsubtractor mog, mog2 , gmg?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am testing in my application opencv's backgroundSubtractors mog, mog2 and gmg.
All 3 reduce the FPS of my application ALOT. With mog and mog2 I get  around 17 fps and with gmg I fall down to 5!

I have re-examined my code and I know I pass around the images as references. There is 1 deep copy involved when grabbing the image from camera, but other than that I work with pointers.

Are the algorithms THAT power hungry?
Note that I run only one subtraction method  at a time on CPU (not gpu). 
The processor is a core i7 though and it seems reasonable to assumd in should be able to cope.
Or am I wrong ?

Comment: I think 17fps for a CPU-based MOG background subtractor is pretty nice.

Comment: that soothes the agony in me :) is there a site with backgroundSubtractors benchmarking?